# Urwid raising (maxcol,) = size too many values to unpack

Tags: python, urwid

I'm trying to create an Urwid UI for a robot. The layout I have in mind is made of three horizontal areas:

- One liner message (like "unknown key pressed")
- Running log messages (anything that happens in the robot)
- Watched variables I'd like to always be displayed

I created this code resulting in the screenshotted layout:

```py
brief_message = urwid.Text(u'Robot starting...')
log_messages = urwid.Text('running log messages here')
variables = urwid.Text('k=v variable list here')
body = urwid.Pile([
    #urwid.Filler(brief_message, height=1),
    urwid.LineBox(urwid.Filler(log_messages, valign='bottom', top=1)),
    urwid.LineBox(urwid.Filler(variables, valign='top', bottom=1)),
])
loop = urwid.MainLoop(body)
loop.run()
```

[image: screenshot of resulting layout]

The problem is that if I uncomment `urwid.Filler(brief_message, height=1)` line, I get an exception and I'm not sure why:

```
[ full traceback snipped ]
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 1001, in render
    (maxcol,) = size
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

I [understand](https://github.com/urwid/urwid/issues/376) this happens because a flow widget is treated like a box widget, but I thought wrapping `brief_message` with an `urwid.Filler` is exactly what I'm supposed to do. Further, if I remove `height=1` from the Filler the program works, but `brief_message`'s height is a third of the screen, which isn't what I want - it should be a oneliner.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#urwid.Filler) for `urwid.Filler` it says:

> If body is a flow widget then height must be 'flow' and min_height will be ignored.

You can't set set to the height to 1 or anything except flow if you are using flow widget like `urwid.Text` as the body.

As far as actually getting the result you're looking for, what follows is my best guess. I don't have an appropriate test environment set up so YMMV.

Looking at the [documentation](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#urwid.Pile) for Pile you can pass tuples with a height value and it will be treated as a box widget. So you might try

```
body = urwid.Pile([
    (1, urwid.Filler(brief_message)),
    urwid.LineBox(urwid.Filler(log_messages, valign='bottom', top=1)),
    urwid.LineBox(urwid.Filler(variables, valign='top', bottom=1)),
])
```

Comment: Didn't notice the documentation about flow widgets in `Filler`, thank you. But I'm afraid passing the tuple for `Pile` still doesn't work (same `ValueError`). :-(

Comment: Does using setting the height of the Filler via the tuple in the Pile's widget_list array work? It should collapse the valign amount to fit instead of expanding.